# Using cached artifacts in Maven to avoid redundant builds?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have a Maven 3 multi-module project (~50 modules) which is stored in Git. Multiple developers are working on this code and building it, and we also have automated build machines that run cold builds on every push.

Most individual changelogs alter code in a fairly small number of modules, so it's a waste of time to rebuild the entire source tree with every change. However, I still want the final result of running the parent project build to be the same as if it had built the entire codebase. And I don't want to start manually versioning modules, as this would become a nightmare of criss-crossing version updates.

What I would like to do is add a plugin which intercepts some step in build or install, and takes a hash of the module contents (ideally pulled from Git), then looks in a shared binary repository for an artifact stored under that hash. If one is found, it uses that artifact and doesn't even execute the full build. If it finds nothing in the cache it performs the build as normal, then stores its artifact in the cache. It would also be good to rebuild any modules which have dependencies (direct or transient) which themselves had a cache miss.

Is there anything out there which does anything like this already? If not, what would be the cleanest way to go about adding it to Maven? It seems like plugins might be able to accomplish it, but for a couple pieces I'm having trouble finding the right way to attach to Maven. Specifically:

1. How can you intercept the "install" goal to check the cache, and only invoke the module's 'native' install goal on a cache miss?
2. How should a plugin pass state from one module to another regarding which cache misses have occurred in order to force rebuilds of dependencies with changes?

I'm also open to completely different ways to achieve the same end result (fewer redundant builds) although the more drastic the solution the less value it has for me in the near term.

Comment: Are you using Jenkins? You can configure jenkins to build only the changed modules (incremental build called) which is supported by maven using `mvn -am -amd -pl module clean install` using a local repository should reduce the build time dramatically.

Comment: Unfortunately no. We're using Bamboo, and I believe either it or our scripts cause the local repository to be empty for every build.

Comment: If your scripts clean the local repository you have to stuck with the full builds otherwise you could have changed that. Based on the docs bamboo does not support incremental builds from UI etc. but you can do that on Maven's command line and with some scripting. May be it's enought to build every night with a clean build instead of every build `mvn -pl module -amd package`.  You can and should of course use a repository manager to store those artifacts and let maven do the work.

Comment: Just a comment on best practices - if you follow the rule of one-build-artifact-per-repo it makes everything simple. More project repos, more Jenkins jobs - but simple.

Answer (score 1):

I have previously implemented a more complicated solution with artifact version manipulation and deployment to private Maven repository. However, I think this will fit your needs better and is somewhat more simple:

1. Split your build into multiple builds (e.g., with a single build per module using maven `-pl` argument).
2. Setup parent-child relationships between these builds. (Bamboo even has additional support for figuring out Maven dependencies, but I'm not sure how it works.)
3. Configure Maven settings.xml to use a different local repository location - specify a new directory inside your build working directory. See docs: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html
4. Use `mvn install` goal to ensure newly built artifacts are added to local repository
5. Use Bamboo artifact sharing to expose built artifacts from local repository - you should probably filter this to include only the package(s) you're interested in
6. Set dependent builds to download all artifacts from parent builds and put them into proper subdirectory of local repository (which is customized to be in working directory)

This should even work for feature branch builds thanks to the way Bamboo handles parent-child relations for branch builds.

Note that this implies that Maven will redownload all other dependencies, so you should use a proxy private Maven repository on local network, such as Artifactory or Nexus.

If you want, I can also describe the more complicated scenario I've already implemented that involves modifying artifact versions and deploying to private Maven repository.

Answer (score 0):

The Jenkins plugin allows you to manage/minimize dependent builds

- whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built (determined by Maven)
- after other projects are built (manually via Jenkins jobs)

And if you do a 'mvn deploy' to save the build into your corporate Maven repo then you don't have to worry about dependencies when builds run on slave Jenkins machines.  The result is that no module is ever built unless it or one of its dependencies has changed.

Hopefully you can apply these principles to a solution with Bamboo.