# How to reuse a docker image from an ealier multi-stage build?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

this is my dockerfile:

```
ARG BUILD_PATH=/usr/app


# Building image
FROM maven:3.8.3-openjdk-17 AS maven
ARG BUILD_PATH
RUN mkdir -p $BUILD_PATH
WORKDIR $BUILD_PATH
COPY . . 
RUN mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip


# Final image
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine
ARG BUILD_PATH
COPY --from=maven $BUILD_PATH/target/app.jar /

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

Every time I build my application using `docker build -t name .`, docker will build the maven image again, which will download all the project's dependencies and package the app and that takes a while. I want to know if there is a way to make docker reuse an image from an earlier build (which will have all the project's dependencies already downloaded) to package the jar that will be used in the final build.

Comment: Does [docker build with maven - how to prevent re-downloading dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60522767/docker-build-with-maven-how-to-prevent-re-downloading-dependencies) have the answer you need?  As a first step if you only `COPY pom.xml` into the image and `RUN mvn dependency:resolve`, you won't have to re-run dependency downloads on every code change, but there are some additional complexities that question discusses.

Comment: @DavidMaze yes, how did I not find that :/ Thanks